# Fedora 38 multimedia playback requires changing audio device in system control center to start playback - How can I fix this?

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, wayland, pipewire

I'm having a problem with my Fedora 38.

Quite strange behavior occurs when trying to play multimedia.

When opening a video on YouTube, or a song on Deezer/Spotify web, it doesn't play, it stays on hold. Playback only starts when I go to the system's control center and change the audio device (according to the screenshot, whatever I select plays, I didn't find any pattern, just changing it works).

Has anyone experienced something like this, or know of a way to resolve it?

I'm trying to debug the problem to identify what's going on. I don't know if it's a conflict with drivers, or if it's a problem with my peripherals (which are connected via Thunderbolt).

OS: Fedora 38
GUI: Gnome 44.1 (over Wayland)
Kernel: Linux 6.2.14-300.fc38.x86_64
Device: Avell A60 MUV (Intel Mobo) | i7 9th | GTX1660Ti

[image: System Control | Audio Selection]

Answer (score 0):

1. Get list of outputs IDs:

$ pactl list sinks

..Or this more readable:

$ pacmd list-sinks | grep -e 'name:' -e 'index:'

2. Then specify wich want to be the default:

$ pactl set-default-sink [id]

Like "pactl set-default-sink 2"

Good luck !